# Using Database to call objects

Tags: android, database

I need some advice. I want to implement a set up, which has 4 static saved objects saved in a database. How would a user select one of these objects to use in a service... When using a SQLDatabase, do you have to create a database every time the app starts.
Any advice welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When the application starts for the first time the database is created. 
The SQLite database saves the information you need into the database, and isnt erased until you allow the user to delete it or update the database.

You can find a very good tutorial on using a database [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

EDIT:

It has means for you to allow the user to update the database also, such as information,names,numbers,ect.